# Getting error when accessing the WebService

Tags: .net, xml

I have exposed a bunch of webservice from which I send several data. The first method will be getting the current datetime from the server. Then rest of the services will be called. Everything works fine.
All the webservices will be tested daily. But once in a week, I am getting the below error.

> ExceptionData
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
>   There was an exception running the
>   extensions specified in the config
>   file. --->  System.Xml.XmlException:
>   Data at the root level is invalid.
>   Line 1, position 1.       at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception
>   e)       at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String
>   res, String arg)       at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
>   at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
>   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
>   at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument
>   doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean
>   preserveWhitespace)       at
>   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader
>   reader)       at
>   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(Stream
>   inStream)       at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapMessage.RunExtensions(SoapExtension[]
>   extensions, Boolean throwOnException) 
>   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()

Can anyone explain what sort of error it is?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please give some code, how you load the XML document?

Comment: Generally with a blind guess, I would say your having some DateTime functionality/math in your service which leads to an exception (once a week).

Answer (score 1):

When you have XML parser errors on line 1, it usually means the file it's trying to parse is not an XML file. It looks like a config file should be an XML file and it's not, or it's not recognizable as one. It you have an error on a different line and column, I'd say this was an format problem in an XML file, but that doesn't appear to be the case here. It's probably not an XML file at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe you've a white space, line break or any character before

```
<?xml version.... (XML declaration).
```

Comment: or invisible char (ex. in "UTF with BOM" encoding.